# ST instruction of avr in microchip stuio (avr studio) nor working as expected

Tags: avr, assembly

I am trying to understand indirect addressing in avr and tried the following code :

```
ldi r31, 0x28
ldi r26, 0x2c
ldi r27, 0x00
st X+, r31
```

when r26 and r27 are loaded the simulator shows X register as 0x002c and the value in r31 is 0x28 (which is expected). However when the ST instruction is executed the X register and resultingly r26) are updated correctly to 0x2d but the value in data registers location 0x2c is still zero. (as per my understanding it should be 0x28, the value in r31)

what am I doing incorrectly here??
Here is an image of where exactly I am looking at :

[image]

Comment: Are you looking at the memory mapped address 0x002c, which is not the same as io mapped address 0x002c? On which AVR model this is?

Comment: I'm working with atmega328p and I am looking at io mapped addresses. I've added a screen shot of where I'm looking at

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason here. the register I am trying to write to is a "reserved" register that is it cannot be written to.

[image]

I tried the same code with 0x4c (the SPDR register) and it works perfectly.